# Probability of Team A shooting a given percentage from 3-point range

Tags: probability

I would like to find a formula I can use to determine the probability of Team A shooting a specific percentage from 3-point range against Team B given Team A's overall average as well as the percentage Team B allows their opponent to shoot.

Example: What is the probability Team A will shoot 43% from 3-point range given their season average is 37% combined with the fact that, on average, Team B allows their opponent to shoot 36% from 3-point range?

Comment: This is not well specified IMO and therefore it does not admit a reasonable answer. Specifically: Team A shoots 43% but that was against teams that allow in average how much? And Team B allows 36% but that was against teams that in average shoot how much?

Comment: Assume that all teams faced by both A and B shoot an average between 30-40%, never higher or lower.  In a real life application there are 30 NBA teams so it would be lengthy to list all the percentages here but no team shoots less than 30% or higher than 40% for the season although the game by game percentages have a much wider range (roughly 15-55%).